# typedef a C++ function to be usable on Windows and Linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, winapi, typedef

I have some huge C++ code base in Windows (WIN32 API) and now I want to port it to Linux too. However, changing the code is not a good idea because there will be two copies of file, for Linux and Windows.

Instead what I thought is, to have a header file with typedef of all WIN32 specific declarations to Linux declarations and include it appropriately.

```
#ifdef __gnu_linux__
#include "linuxCPPTypeDef.h"
#endif
```

linuxCPPTypeDef.h will contain`typedef unsigned int DWORD;`, etc.

Till here it is fine. The trickier part is.. my code is using the standard `min` function in a lot of places but g++ doesn't understand it (needs `std::min`).

Is there a way I can do a declaration in my header file so that I don't have to change the function everywhere in the code?

Comment: Use as much as possible standard C++ this way you ensure your code is as portable as possible.

Comment: you mean like `using std::min` ?  But `std::min` should work with Windows compilers also.

Comment: BTW in cases where the name or parameter order doesn't match, an `inline` function is helpful.

Comment: Yes std::min. But I don't want to change it in 100 places. What is a quick fix to just write a typedef or something that will define my usage of min as std::min ?

Comment: I already told you, `using std::min;` will do it.

Comment: Your time will be well spent investigating *why* `min` seems to work on windows and not on linux.

Comment: Well, I was trying to know if we could do something from header file, rather than touching CPP file.
Moreover, the using thing didn't work.

Comment: `using std::min;` will work.  Unless there's something you're not telling us, such as `std::min` isn't working because you haven't included its header.  Or that your code actually uses the `MIN` macro and not `min`.

Comment: @BenVoigt I think you should make `using std::min;` an answer.

Comment: @techEnthusiast AFAIK, windows defines a macro for `min`, you can do the same, or better, use standard C++ as much as possible

Comment: I would recommend `#undef min`, `#undef max` in Windows and use `std::min` and `std::max` everywhere.

Comment: @rodrigo: A better idea is to `#define NOMINMAX` prior to including `<windows.h>`. That way you never have to deal with those macros. If you do, consider using `#pragma push_macro` prior to `#undef`ing it.

Comment: @IInspectable: Sure! I already saw the answer by Tom below. It is undoubtly better this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <algorithm>
using std::min;
using std::max;
```

However, if you're talking about the ones from Windows.h, it defines these as macros, not as functions.  The compiler will treat them differently, in subtle ways that are hard to resolve.  For instance, this doesn't work:

```
#include <algorithm>
using std::min;
using std::max;

int Foo() {
    return 5 * min(1, 3.0);
}
```

because the compiler can't deduce the template type for `std::min`; it could be `int` or `double`.  You have to explicitly tell it `std::min<int>(1, 3.0)`.

It might be tempting to define your own macro versions:

```
#define min(x,y) ((x) < (y) ? (x) : (y))
```

or similar; however, anywhere such a definition is present, most of the GNU STL headers can't be used, because they assume that `min` and `max` are not defined as preprocessor macros.

All in all, you're better off rewriting your Windows code to use `std::min` and `std::max` explicitly.  To make this work, you'll have to `#define NOMINMAX` before you `#include <windows.h>`.